# cannot mock import statement using unittest.patch

Tags: python, python-2.7, magicmock

I have an import statement inside a function and I want to mock that import statement using patch, but couldn't.

```
    class A():
      """mock object"""
      @staticmethod
      def run():
        print('ran')

    @patch('something')
    def test_run(self, something):
      something = A()

      # my function has this statement
      from something import run

      run(....)
```

got

```
    E   TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'something'
```